# Por que os endereços web de CDN não especificam protocolo?

Tags: http, cdn

Normalmente os endereços web começam com `http://` ou `https://`, mas os endereços de CDN como do jQuery e do Bootstrap começam com `//`.

Exemplo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

e

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

O que isso significa?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso indica ao browser para **usar o mesmo protocolo que estiver na barra de endereço** da página que está fazendo a requisição.

Isso quer dizer que:

- se você estiver em uma página servida através de HTTP, a requisição será feita ao CDN HTTP
- se você estiver em uma página servida através de HTTPS, a requisição será feita ao CDN HTTPS

**Exemplo**

Suponha que tenho um site em `www.meusite.com.br`, e nele coloco uma referência igual a que você indicou:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

No IIS, eu configuro para permitir que a minha página seja servida tanto por HTTP, como por HTTPS.

Quando o usuário acessar `http://www.meusite.com.br`, o browser vai buscar o javascript em `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`.

Quando o usuário acessar `https://www.meusite.com.br`, o browser vai buscar o javascript em `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js`.

Comment: Ou seja, isso não tem nada a ver com CDN, você pode utilizar a mesma técnica em qualquer site habilitado para responder tanto em http quanto https.