# Como devo trabalhar em relaçao a links do Bootstrap e JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

Qual a melhor forma de se trabalhar com Bootstrap ou JavaScript?

1. Referenciar pela CDN

   ```
   link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   ```
2. Referenciar pelo arquivo baixado

   ```
   link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css
   ```

Comment: Bruno, procure ser mais claro em suas perguntas assim o pessoal consegue entender o seu problema e te ajudar.

Comment: Referencie dos arquivos baixados assim você ganha em performasse pois seu site não vai precisar baixar os arquivos de outros site, estando tudo alocado no seu próprio servidor.

Comment: Não fique na mão do CDN, se ele estiver offline seu site vai ficar todo quebrado! Pense melhor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As duas formas são complementares e ambas com suas respectivas vantagens de desvantagens.

Idealmente, você deve preferir sempre a versão que está no CDN, pois, como é óbvio, está no CDN. Um arquivo no CDN normalmente será carregado muito mais rápido que um no próprio servidor, ainda mais quando se tratando de Bootstrap e Jquery, que são utilizados na grande maioria dos sites. Isso acontece porque, se o seu cliente já tiver acessado qualquer outro site que utiliza o mesmo arquivo na CDN, o cliente já terá a versão utilizada baixada em seu computador e, assim, utilizará a mesma. Não se preocupe, o navegador faz todo o trabalho pesado por você.

Mas se acontecer do cliente não possuir a versão já baixada e a conexão com o servidor CDN estiver instável, sua aplicação não conseguirá carregar corretamente. Depender de aplicações externas, que não temos controle, nem sempre é uma boa opção. Se o arquivo for pequeno e não prejudicar o carregamento da sua aplicação, você pode utilizar apenas a versão local, apontando para o arquivo no seu próprio servidor.

Caso queira utilizar as vantagens das duas soluções, aconselho você a importar o arquivo direto do CDN e criar um *fallback* com JavaScript para que, se o arquivo não for carregado com sucesso, importe a sua versão local. Desta forma, se o CDN estiver disponível, utilizará todas as vantagens do mesmo, mas quando não, carregará a versão local, mesmo demandando mais tempo de carregamento da aplicação, mas evitando que a mesma fique quebrada.

É bastante comum ver esta abordagem na importação do jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Na primeira linha é importado a biblioteca a partir do que seria equivalente ao CDN. Se esta requisição falhar, o objeto `window.jQuery` continuará a ser nulo, fazendo com que na segunda linha seja criado o *script* de importação do arquivo local.

> **Nota**: inclusive nada te impede utilizar outro serviço CDN como *fallback*, mas igualmente ele possuiria os mesmos problemas e, idealmente, teria que possuir outro *fallback* para ele; depende muito do projeto que está fazendo, mas sinceramente nunca vi alguma aplicação que utilizasse múltiplos *fallbacks* e que foi prejudicada por não utilizar.

**Leituras adicionais**

- [Sobre fallback para CDN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26543/5878)
- [Por que os endereços web de CDN não especificam protocolo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13002/5878)
- [Usar arquivos locais caso CDN esteja Offline](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63309/5878)
- [Servir bibliotecas com CDN ou Servidor próprio?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/66400/5878)
- [Criando um CDN - content delivery network](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/119766/5878)
- [Diferenças entre utilização de Cache e CDN](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189323/5878)

Comment: Eu uso diversas libs, jquery, bootstrap, select2, datatables e outras. Tudo via cdn, teria que fazer esse fallback para cada uma delas?

Comment: @L.J basicamente, sim, ou você compacta tudo em um arquivo só e importa apenas ele. Fazer isso pode ser até mais rápido que múltiplas requisições a vários CDNs.

Comment: Você diz colocar todas requisições em um arquivo e chamar esse arquivo nas páginas? Isso seria ótimo. Como é feito isso?