# É recomendado utilizar <link href="#"> ou <script src="#"> com endereços externos?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se existe algum jeito correto (ou mais eficiente) de como utilizar arquivos .css ou .js já existentes. Se é aconselhável fazer requisição para endereços externos ou o ideal é utilizar dentro da minha aplicação.

Exemplo:
Utilizando bootstrap, é melhor realizar download e colocar na minha aplicação (pasta Content)

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link href="~/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css1/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Ou é melhor utilizar via endereço externo?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: O mais seguro é você ter dentro de sua aplicação.

Comment: @MayconF.Castro existe algum motivo por trás disso? Ou só pelo fato de fazer uma requisição externa já torna inseguro?

Comment: Saudações, Bruno; poderia substituir as imagens da sua pergunta pelo código propriamente dito? Postá-los em forma de imagem prejudica o sistema de buscas do site e a leitura da pergunta de vários usuários, pois as imagens não são exibidas em todos os lugares.

Comment: Eu penso que a qualquer momento o link externo possa ficar fora do ar ou coisa assim, sendo assim sempre prefiro colocar dentro das minhas aplicações.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como devo trabalhar em relaçao a links do Bootstrap e JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303645/como-devo-trabalhar-em-rela%c3%a7ao-a-links-do-bootstrap-e-javascript)

Comment: O maior ganho que vc tem utilizando os arquivos dentro do projeto e não com links externos é que vc **nunca sofrerá o risco de um link de algum arquivo estar quebrado, devido à uma queda de servidor por exemplo**.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editado. Sobre essa duplicata, não tinha encontrado ela em minhas pesquisas, porém a resposta de lá acredito ser a mais completa.